# Computing taylor series for two variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> **Question:** Compute all the terms in the taylor series for the following function around the point $(1,1)$ $$f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$$

**My attempt:**

$$f_x= 2x, \ f_y= 2y, \ f_{xx}= 2, \ f_{yy}=2$$

So we have $$f(x,y)= f(1,1) +f_x(1,1).(x-1)+f_y(1,1).(y-1)+f_{xx}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)^2}{2!}+f_{yy}(1,1).\frac{(y-1)^2}{2!}$$

$$f(x,y) = 2+2(x-1)+2(y-1)+(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2$$

Is this method correct, and would it work for any function with two or more random variables?

Comment: It would be good to mention $f_{xy} = 0.$

Comment: What would be the case if $f_{xy}$ wasn't zero?

Comment: You would need to deal with it. For example the function $xy$ expanded about $(1,1)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have $$f(x,y)= f(1,1) +f_x(1,1).(x-1)+f_y(1,1).(y-1)+f_{xx}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)^2}{2!}+2f_{xy}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{2!}+f_{yy}(1,1).\frac{(y-1)^2}{2!}$$

It's $2f_{xy}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{2!}$ instead of $f_{xy}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{2!}+f_{yx}(1,1).\frac{(x-1)(y-1)}{2!}$ because $f_{xy}=f_{yx}$

In your case the fact that $f_{xy}=0$ makes your answer correct in this case, but not suitable for generalisation.